# Modifying data using SOQL?

Tags: soql, php, dml

I'm using SOQL along with the SOAP API in order to pull a certain set of data to my webpage. However, I want to modify this data (two custom fields) and update the records in Salesforce itself. As I understand, SOQL cannot do this. How can I go about doing this?

Here's how I SELECT the records:

```
$query = "SELECT Field1__c, Field2__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'TestName'";
```

This is using PHP by the way.

Comment: Use the update call: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_update.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_%28Enterprise%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the various examples in [Getting Started with the Force.com Toolkit for PHP](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP).

You use SOQL to query:

```
$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
```

but to update you pass the list of changed records:

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->update($records, 'Contact');
```

Comment: Can you explain me what are the type of $records? as I'm using array of sObject

Comment: I'm getting success in response, but salesforce field is not updated

Comment: I can not update 'contact' table only other table are successfully updated..Can u pls help me for solving this issue

Comment: See e.g. [What is Dynamic Typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394711/what-is-dynamic-typing): the type depends on what is on the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: On only being able to update some SObjects, that is usually a profile issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following example code. First you have select the record and then update result set.

```
$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email,Phone  from Contact where Email='myemail@mail.in'"; $response = $connection->query($query);

/*Make changes in result array and then pass to update function*/
    $array = array();  foreach ($response as $contact)  {
         
       $contact->fields->Phone = 123456789;
         
        $array[] = $contact;
       
    }
    $result = $connection->update($array, 'Contact');
```